# How to divide a given number between the ranges as shown below?

Tags: sql, plsql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Given Number: 2111.03

T1 data:

| Name | No |
| --- | --- |
| AAA | 2111.03 |

T2 data:

| Name | Start Range | End Range |
| --- | --- | --- |
| AAA | 0 | 100 |
| AAA | 100 | 130 |
| AAA | 130 | 155 |
| AAA | 155 | 99990 |

**Expected Output:** Number should  go though each range and subtract by the max range, need to show the remaining number at the end.

| Name | No |
| --- | --- |
| AAA | 100 |
| AAA | 30 |
| AAA | 55 |
| AAA | 1926.03 |

Please help me write a query

Please help me to write a query in SQL, PLSQL.

Comment: Can you please show how the result numbers are computed? I have no idea how you arrive at 1926.03 (2111.03 - 155 = 1956.03) Similarly how does 155 - 130 = 55???

Comment: Agree with @AdrianMaxwell.  I think I have a solution for you in Snowflake, but I think your final table should be 100, 30, 25, and 1956.03, right?

Comment: Hi @AdrianMaxwell,

Please find the required output in the below format 

No: 2111.03

Start  End Range  max end range-startrange 
-----  -------  ----------------------------
0    100          100
100   130          30
130    155          55
155    99999(2111.03)  1926.03

Comment: why have you tagged the question as `PLSQL` and `Snowflake`? Snowflake is not PLSQL

Comment: @SimeonPilgrim scope creep

Comment: There is a [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77643080/edit) link under the question to your question so that you may make corrections or add further information to it. In particular these comments are NOT a good vehicle for information that requires formatting. **Also** I asked for **how** you arrived at the result so I would expect calculations in this style (2111.03 - 155 = 1956.03). So, you haven't answered my original question.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because no own attempt to solve the problem is visible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assume you have transposed the 2,5 of the example data.

using to CTE's for the example data:

```
with t1(name, no) as (
    select * from values 
        ('AAA',2111.03),
        ('BBB',112),
        ('CCC',1266.79)
        
), t2(name, start_range, end_range) as (
    select * from values
        ('AAA', 0, 100),
        ('AAA', 100, 130),
        ('AAA', 130, 155),
        ('AAA', 155, 9999),
        ('BBB', 0, 100),
        ('BBB', 100, 130),
        ('BBB', 130, 155),
        ('BBB', 155, 9999),
        ('CCC', 0, 100),
        ('CCC', 100, 120),
        ('CCC', 120, 120)
)
```

this SQL joins the tables, and provides the values shown in the table:

```
select t1.name
    ,case 
        when row_number()over(partition by t1.name order by start_range desc, end_range desc) = 1 then greatest(0, no - t2.start_range)
        when t1.no < t2.end_range then greatest(0, no - t2.start_range)
        else t2.end_range-t2.start_range
     end as no
from t1
join t2 
    on t1.name = t2.name
order by 1, start_range;
```

[image]

Comment: Hi @Simeon Pilgrim,

Thanks for the query but as I mentioned above, same scenario is not working for below case: 

Number: 1266.79 
Range: 1-100, 100-120,120-120. 

Please have a look once

Comment: @chinnu what is the expected result, the I stated works as "I would intend" you have not shown we a result "I do not expect" please say what you expect, and why!

Answer (score 0):

I made some assumptions based on your question, as it wasn't clear.  If you need adjustment, let me know.  The following uses Snowflake's SQL and I added a BBB value in the data to show values that fall short of the ranges, just in case:

```
create or replace temp table tab1 (name string, no float) as
select name, no
from (values ('AAA',2111.03),('BBB',112) x (name,no));

create or replace temp table tab2 (name string, start_range number, end_range number) as
select name, start_range, end_range
from (values ('AAA',0,100),('AAA',100,130),('AAA',130,155),('AAA',155,99990),('BBB',0,100),('BBB',100,130),('BBB',130,155),('BBB',155,99990) x (name, start_range, end_range));
```

solution:

```
select t1.name
     , t1.no
     , sum(t2.end_range) over (partition by t2.name order by end_range, start_range rows between UNBOUNDED PRECEDING and CURRENT ROW) as max_sum
     , lag(t2.end_range) over (partition by t2.name order by end_range, start_range) as max_last
     , case when no >= max_sum then end_range-start_range
            else  
                case when no-max_last > 0 then no-max_last
                     else 0
                     end
            end as new_no
from tab1 t1
join tab2 t2
  on t1.name = t2.name;
```

Comment: Hi Mike Walton,

Thank you for your immediate response, but I have another scenario like this and it is not working for it. Please suggest

Please use the update create table statements and let me know.

create or replace temp table tab1 (name string, no float) as
select name, no
from (values ('AAA',2111.03),('BBB',112),('CCC',1266.79) x (name,no));

Comment: create or replace temp table tab2 (name string, start_range number, end_range number) as
select name, start_range, end_range
from (values ('AAA',0,100),('AAA',100,130),('AAA',130,155),('AAA',155,99990),('BBB',0,100),('BBB',100,130),('BBB',130,155),('BBB',155,99990),('CCC',0,100),('CCC',100,120),('CCC',120,120) x (name, start_range, end_range));

Comment: A scenario where you have multiple ranges that end in the same number.  Just need to add to the order by clauses.  Let me update.

Comment: Thanks for the update @Mike Walton, final number is not populating even order by change.

Comment: @chinnu Looking in more depth, I don't know what you want in the output.  In your tab1 there is no bucket for the rest of the number to fill into, so how do you want that to work?  You need a place for that quantity to land.

Answer (score 0):

You can take advantage of `WINDOW` function and `CASE..WHEN` as follows:

```
with t1(name, no) as (
    select 'AAA',2111.03 FROM DUAL
), t2(name, start_range, end_range) as (
    select 'AAA', 0, 100 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    select 'AAA', 100, 130 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    select 'AAA', 130, 155 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    select 'AAA', 155, 9999 FROM DUAL 
)
SELECT
    T1.NAME,
    CASE
        WHEN T1.NO > SUM(T2.END_RANGE - T2.START_RANGE)
                     OVER(PARTITION BY T2.NAME
                          ORDER BY
                             T2.START_RANGE
                     ) THEN
            T2.END_RANGE - T2.START_RANGE
        ELSE
            T1.NO - COALESCE(SUM(T2.END_RANGE - T2.START_RANGE)
                    OVER(PARTITION BY T2.NAME
                         ORDER BY
                            T2.START_RANGE
                ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING
                    ), T2.START_RANGE)
    END AS NUM
  FROM
         T1
      JOIN T2 ON T1.NAME = T2.NAME
       AND T1.NO >= T2.START_RANGE;
```

[DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/8brbjfjv)

Comment: Hi @ORA-01017,

Thanks for the update but same logic is not working for the below scenario. 

 Number: 1266.79 Range: 1-100, 100-120,120-120. Please have a look once

Comment: with t1(name, no) as (
    select 'AAA',1266.79 FROM DUAL
), t2(name, start_range, end_range) as (
    select 'AAA', 0, 100 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    select 'AAA', 100, 120 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    select 'AAA', 120, 120 FROM DUAL
)

Comment: It is working as expected when you have last range with 0 dofference, what do you expect? Even such scenario was not mentioned in the question. Try to ask question more specifically. Answers here are using your sample data and expected output as the base for it.